# Apache Nutch 2.3: throwing Error Failed with exit value 255

Tags: hadoop, nutch

I'm using apache nutch 2.3 version.
My hadoop version is 2.6.0.Hadoop is running on single node.

When I run following command of nutch

```
./crawl --index ~/test/seed ~/test -1
```

The output of the above command is following.

```
InjectorJob: starting at 2016-01-04 12:03:26
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: --index
InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.memory.store.MemStore as the    
Gora storage class.
InjectorJob:    
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input
path does not exist: file:/usr/local/nutch/runtime/local/bin/--index
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus
(FileInputFormat.java:235)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits
(FileInputFormat.java:252)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits
(JobClient.java:1054)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1071)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:983)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs
(UserGroupInformation.java:1190
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal
(JobClient.java:936)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:50)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:231)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:252)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:275)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:284)

Error running:
/usr/local/nutch/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject --index -crawlId    
/home/jalaj/test/seed
Failed with exit value 255.
```

What is the problem with nutch? Should I need to install Apache Gora?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/usr/local/nutch/runtime/local/bin/--index`

Nutch try to read the seed file, but cannot. Please make sure your command is correct.

Hope this helps,

Le Quoc Do

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll check and get back to this.